# How can i use navigation side menu in entire app, even activity class?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm using android **navigation drawer** menu. I want to show **navigation drawer** in my **all activities class**. If i  want to use it what i need to do actually. If anyone give tips it'll very helpful.

Comment: Make `abstract` class as a `BaseActivity` and extends your all activities with `BaseActivity`.

Comment: Bro piyush, I didn't get u. Will u clear me with an example.

Comment: add navigation drawer in each of your layouts

Answer (score 1):

Make a `BaseActivity` Activity, which will be extended by every other Activity.
The layout of the `BaseActivity` will be a `DrawerLayout`, that contains a `FrameLayout` and the Navigation Drawer. It will look something like this (In this case, the Navigation Drawer is a `RecyclerView`) -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Content-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/base_frame"/>
    <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_rv"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Make the `FrameLayout` a `protected` class field, and in every Activity that extends the `BaseActivity`, inflate the layout as such -

```
 getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_activity, baseFrameLayout);
```

Make the `BaseActivity` handle all interactions with the Navigation Drawer (selecting items, switching Activities, etc...).